# No such module purelayout in swift with manual installation?

Tags: swift

I have been at this for over an hour. I am desperate.

I am trying to implement this here https://github.com/enisgayretli/EGFloatingTextField and this is my previous question [Best way to achieve UILabel animation effect in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38189672/best-way-to-achieve-uilabel-animation-effect-in-swift/38189954?noredirect=1#comment63807398_38189954)

For the text field to work I need to import Purelayout. I'm working in swift and this is where things don't work- I've tried all the methods on the purelayout github but can't for the life of me import purelayout.

No matter what I do I get no such module purelayout. I am trying to do the manual installation and I have 1. Dragged and copied the purelayout source files into my project 2. Written the import Purelayout.h line in my bridging header

Where am I going wrong here? Am I configuring my header wrong? When I drag the files in it wants to configure a new Bridger and creates a blank file.. Could this be the problem?

My project will not compile. I can't understand this.

Comment: I have same issue.. Have you found any solution for this issue ??

Comment: Apparently you don't need the import statement for it to work